# Changing USB Storage Device Permissions from within OS X Kernel Space

Tags: macos, usb, kernel

In OS X kernel space, is there a way to upgrade the permissions of a mounted USB storage device, a DOK, say, from read only to read/write?

I use the init method of IOMedia:

```
 bool init(
    UInt64 base, 
    UInt64 size, 
    UInt64 preferredBlockSize, 
    IOMediaAttributeMask attributes, 
    bool isWhole, 
    bool isWritable, 
    const char *contentHint = 0, 
    OSDictionary *properties = 0);
```

to create and attach the child media IOStorage object with *isWritable* set to false, which sets the permissions of the USB device to read only, but later, I need to change the permissions to read/write without un-mounting and remounting.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by initially not mounting the device and when appropriate, either mounting it as read-only or read-write based on external criteria.